# elasticsearch 5.6.3 compatible spring data elasticsearch version

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

I am using spring boot 1.5.7.RELEASE, spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.2.RELEASE and elasticsearch 5.6.3. However, when building with maven it seems to dowload elasticsearch 2.4.6.
When I try to force elasticsearch 5.6.3 through pom file I receive runtime exception which shows missing runtime dependencies.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Spring Data Elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch) you need Spring Data Elasticsearch version 3.0.0.RC2 to support Elasticsearch 5.5. Not sure if this means running against 5.6.3 on the server will work (it might). And this spring data version also requires Spring 5 IIRC.

Not sure if spring boot 1.5.7 will even work with Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.0.0 - you might have to wait for Spring Boot 2.0.

You'll need to override the version of Spring Data that spring boot is pulling in (not just the version of elastic search).

Answer (score 0):

After looking into POM files, I saw that spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.7.RELEASE.pom  downloads elasticsearch.version 2.4.6.Trying to force different elastic version in pom does not work.
So an upgrade in spring boot is required.